# Select in template parents foreign key

Tags: django, django-templates

i have in mu Model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_administrator = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}\'s profile'.format(self.user.username)

class Company(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)
    name = models.CharField( max_length=200)

class Invitation(models.Model):

    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)

    date = models.ManyToManyField(Date)
    speaker = models.ForeignKey(Speaker, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    invited_to = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    talk = models.ManyToManyField(Talk)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.speaker.name + ' by ' + self.invited_to.name
class Speaker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    talk = models.ManyToManyField(Talk)
```

so in my view i send `invites = Invitation.objects.all()`

and what i need in my template is to access Profile's name: Invitation.invited_to.Company.Profile.name, and also Invitation.speaker.Company.Profile.name.

Is there any wasy way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your database structure you will be able to get all the speakers and profiles associated with a company in your template, but you won't be able to get a specific profile.

To get all the profiles you can use:

```
{% for invite in invites %}
    {% for profile in invite.invited_to.company.profile_set.all %}
        {{ profile.user.first_name }} {{ profile.user.last_name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This should give you the name for every profile that is in a company that has been invited.

You can do a similar thing to get all the speakers for a company.

```
{% for invite in invites %}
    {% for profile in invite.speaker.company.profile_set.all %}
        {{ profile.user.first_name }} {{ profile.user.last_name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Having **a guess** at what you're trying to do, I imagine you actually want to either use `{{ request.user }}` in your template to get the logged in user or to pass a profile object to the template.